# How to loop using foreach on 'addApiParam' in PHP?

Tags: php, api, foreach

I'm setting up an API and want to loop the params of `<Url>` tag according to the total of the images. I have tried using `foreach` in the params which did not work. Is there any solution that can help solve the problem?

There are two images and the expected result should be:

```
<Url>Image1</Url>
<Url>Image2</Url>
```

[image: Image of the params code]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code.

```
 <?php
   $param = '<Request><Images>';

   foreach($images as $img){
      $param .= '<Url>'.$img.'</Url>';
   }

   $param .= '</Images></Request>';

   $requestGetData->addApiParam('Payload', $param);
 ?>
```